# Android intent for software

Tags: android

Thata code insted
 keyboardview or one of its extended class. You have not shared your RelativeLayout but i think The exception may be because of some problem with your RelativeLayout.

You can put a button to the right of Keyboard like this(res/layout/input.xml):

```
<  com.android.example.LatinKeyboardView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/keyboard"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:keyBackground="@drawable/kb_exagon_base"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any View/ViewGroup as a keyboard layout, Infact you can even set the keyboard layout to a view which is not an instance of keyboardview or one of its extended class. You have not shared your RelativeLayout but i think The exception may be because of some problem with your RelativeLayout.

You can put a button to the right of Keyboard like this(res/layout/input.xml):

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/keyboardLayout"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
 <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView 
     android:id="@+id/keyboardView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
 <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/imageView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

And then return an instance of this layout from **OnCreateInputView**.

Update: 
The statement mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.input, null); in your below comment will throw ClassCastException as the inflated view is not an instance of KeyboardView. 
you need to change it like this:

```
 public View onCreateInputView() {
    mInputView = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.input, null);
    mKeyboardView = (KeyboardView)mInputView.findViewById(R.id.keyboardView);
    mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this); 
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);
    return mInputView; 
}
```

Comment: @totzi10 I didn't understand the issue you are facing, can you provide more information. input is the name of xml file and keyboardView is defined in layout inside of it.

Comment: Sorry, now it go! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

the keyboard pops up from the bottom and you can define the behavior in your manifest using the following line `android:windowSoftInputMode`:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".NAME"
        android:label="@string/appName"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.HOLOorAnyThemeYouWant"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
```

from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) :

> android:windowSoftInputMode
>   How the main window of the activity interacts with the window containing the on-screen soft keyboard. The setting for this attribute affects two things:
>   The state of the soft keyboard — whether it is hidden or visible — when the activity becomes the focus of user attention.
>   The adjustment made to the activity's main window — whether it is resized smaller to make room for the soft keyboard or whether its contents pan to make the current focus visible when part of the window is covered by the soft keyboard.